# Can someone tell the me the data bank which has all the STO-3G basis sets for many electron atoms?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry

I am trying to express the slater orbitals of Helium atom in terms of 3 gaussian functions (STO-3G basis set). Is there any data bank or reference table in which I can find the exponents and coefficients in it ? 
Also in primitive cartesian gaussian , it seems like both $2s$ and $2p$ has the same functional form. For $2p$ it is $x\exp(-\alpha x^{2})$ , $y\exp(-\alpha y^{2})$ and $z\exp(-\alpha z^{2})$. What is for  $2s$ orbital in primitive gaussian function ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A wide range of Gaussian basis sets for all elements can be found at the [Basis Set Exchange](https://www.basissetexchange.org/). Alternatively, you can try to extract that data from the basis set library of a quantum chemistry software package.

The functional form of a primitive cartesian gaussian with $l=0$ is $\exp(-\alpha r^2)$, independent of the $n$ quantum number.

Comment: Extremely sorry